# getElementById resulting in null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone could explain why the spanValue attribute is null in this situation. Basically I'm trying to pull the text within *exampleSpan* and assign it to the variable *"spanValue"*. Once that is done, I use jQuery to locate an input box with the class "testClass", and assign that input box with the placeholder attribute and the value of *"spanValue"*.

```
<span id="exampleSpan" style="display:none;">bla-bla</span>

        var spanValue = document.getElementById('exampleSpan'.value); 
        jQuery(".testClass").attr("placeholder", spanValue);
```

I've been testing with an alert popup with the following line, and that correctly returns the value. I'm guessing this has to do with the way I'm assigning spanValue to the value of exampleSpan - is it copying the location rather than the value, hence the null? Any explanation and example code would be appreciated.

```
    alert(document.getElementById('exampleSpan').innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Misplaced `)`, First you need to use get the element. Since the element is a `SPAN` it doesn't have the value property so use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property

```
var spanElement = document.getElementById('exampleSpan');
var spanValue = spanElement .textContent;
```

Using jQuery

```
//To get the text
var spanValue = $('#exampleSpan').text();

//To get the HTML
var spanValue = $('#exampleSpan').html();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm just going to go jump off a bridge now. :)

Answer (score 4):

You've misplaced a paren.

```
var spanValue = document.getElementById('exampleSpan'.value);
```

And `.value` is for inputs, not spans; you need `.textContent`.

So it should be:

```
var spanValue = document.getElementById('exampleSpan').textContent;
```

Comment: FYI, `SPANElement.value` will return `undefined`

Comment: because it is not Input .. it is span

Answer (score 3):

should be like this

**In Javascript:**

```
var spanValue = document.getElementById('exampleSpan').innerHTML;
```

**In Jquery :**

```
var spanValue = $('#exampleSpan').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
   var spanValue = $("#exempleSpan").text();
  jQuery(".testClass").attr("placeholder", spanValue);
```

Comment: Note, `.val()` is only for form elements

Comment: true, it's text then